# Insert Current TimeStamp in a column databse android

Tags: android, database

I' m trying to add a timestamp column to a database android every time when I receive a new data from my sensor the methode that i am using is to get the time in a textview then it will be added to a new column in the database (Listview) , this is my source code that I am using :

```
public class All extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView l; Helper h;
    TextView t ,t1 ;
    private Timer autoUpdate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all);
       l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        t=findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        t1=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         h=new Helper(All.this);


        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView t = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                Intent x= new Intent(All.this,Details.class);
                x.putExtra("id",t.getText().toString());
                startActivity(x);
            }
        });
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a ");
        String date1 = date.format(c.getTime());
        t1.setText(date1);

        if (MyHandler.m != null) {

        autoUpdate = new Timer();
        autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      String da = MyHandler.m;
                            // Toast.makeText(LoadBalanceActivity.this, da,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      String ancien = t.getText().toString();
                            if (!da.equals(ancien)) {
                                t.setText(da) ;
                                h.AddContact(da);
                                h.add1(t1.getText().toString());
                                //h.rubytoTimeStamp(t1.getText().toString());
                                Cursor cr=h.getAllContant();
                                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(All.this, R.layout.item,cr,new String[]{cr.getColumnName(0),cr.getColumnName(1),cr.getColumnName(2)},
                                        new int[]{R.id.textView, R.id.textView2,R.id.textView4} ,1 );
                                l.setAdapter(adapter);


                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 1000); // updates each .. sec

        }  
    }
}
```

This is On create function that I am using in database :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE contact(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 1   ,nom TEXT, 
     time TEXT   )");
    
}
```

This is My Add function that I am using to add the time in the database :

```
public void add1(String time) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a ");
    String date1 = date.format(c.getTime());
    cv.put("time", date1);
    db.insert("contact", null, cv);

}
```

And this is the function to get the data from database :

```
public Cursor getAllContant()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contact",null);
    return c;

}
```

This is the xml of my item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Time is added succefully in database but in the wrong place , the problem is that the time is located on a new line and not on the 3rd column  Like in the picture below.

[image]

Is there  Something missing?
Please I need your Help

Comment: Add the xml for your item layout to the question as that's where the issue probably is.

Comment: Ok already added

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue is that the add1 method is only inserting a row with the current time and nothing in the **nom** column;
So you are only getting 309 09:23:32 am. The time value passed to the method is not used.

I would also suggest that you don't instantiate (create) a new adapter each time.

Perhaps make the following changes:-

1. Change Add1 in Helper.java to be

:-

```
public void add1(String time) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a ");
    String date1 = date.format(c.getTime());
    cv.put("time", date1);
    cv.put("nom",time); //<<<<<<<<<< Insert the time value passed
    db.insert("contact", null, cv);
}
```

2. then use the following for All.java

:-

```
public class All extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView l; Helper h;
    TextView t ,t1 ;
    private Timer autoUpdate;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    Cursor cr; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all);
       l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        t=findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        t1=findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         h=new Helper(All.this);


        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                TextView t = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                Intent x= new Intent(All.this,Details.class);
                x.putExtra("id",t.getText().toString());
                startActivity(x);
            }
        });
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a ");
        String date1 = date.format(c.getTime());
        t1.setText(date1);

        if (MyHandler.m != null) {

        autoUpdate = new Timer();
        autoUpdate.schedule(new TimerTask() {
          public void run() {

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      String da = MyHandler.m;
                            // Toast.makeText(LoadBalanceActivity.this, da,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      String ancien = t.getText().toString();
                            if (!da.equals(ancien)) {
                                t.setText(da) ;
                                h.AddContact(da);
                                h.add1(t1.getText().toString());
                                //h.rubytoTimeStamp(t1.getText().toString());
                                setOrRefreshListView(); //<<<<<<<<<< REPLACES quite a few lines of code
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 1000); // updates each .. sec

        }  
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< NEW METHOD >>>>>>>>>
    private void setOrRefreshListView() {
        cr = h.getAllContant();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.item,
                    cr,
                    new String[]{cr.getColumnName(0),cr.getColumnName(1),cr.getColumnName(2)},
                    new int[]{R.id.textView,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView4},
                    1
            );
            l.setAdapter(sca);
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(cr);
        }
    }
}
```

- The new setOrRefreshListView method instantiates the adapter when first called and then subsequently refresh list by swapping the old cursor for the changed cursor.
- **NOTE** the call to AddContact was omitted from the testing as the code wasn't included. I assumed that AddContact inserts into another table **BUT** it may be that it inserts into the same table and is perhaps why you get the likes of 305 176 and then 306 09:23:32 am. If what you want is 305 176 09:23:32 am then just use Add1 and pass the 176 via the time (I just used the String TEST).

**Result**

The following is a screen shot with rows added before the change to Add1 and then  rows after changing Add1. The GO button used to mimic the autotimer. The code used was very much yours but with the autotimer/handler code commented out. The Item layout used was yours :-

[image]

using Database Inspector the database looks like (highlight indicates when the change was made) :-

[image]